# Selenium WebDriver: Modal dialog present unhandled alert exception page objects

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am getting Modal Dialog Present error while saving a form and verifying the alert popup.

Code:

Method used for verifying the text of alert pop up

```
def alert_text
  sleep 20
  self.button_save

  alert_element = @browser.switch_to.alert
  alert_element = alert_element.text
  alert_element.accept

  sleep 20
  print message
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because of following line:

```
alert_element = alert_element.text
```

here `alert_element` is storing text and on next line you're calling method `accept` on `alert_element` which is string.

Remove following line from your code:

```
alert_element = alert_element.text
```

Comment: it didnt work.. I have commented out the line alert_element = alert_element.text